# JQuery Passing Each Sibling to a Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, parent-child, siblings

I'm having trouble with the `.siblings().each()` in JQuery.  I have a nested list of checkboxes.  One functionality is that you check a checkbox and it also checks all of the corresponding checkboxes having the same value.  That works.  Then, if you check a parent checkbox then all of the children (siblings) will be selected.  That also works.

What I'm having trouble with is checking a parent checkbox and then calling a function on each child (sibling) to check other checkboxes of the same value.  Basically passing each sibling to the  `checkAllSameUser` function.

Here's the HTML:

```
<ul>
<li><input type='checkbox' class="build-checkbox" value="1"  /> 1</li>
<li><input type='checkbox' class="build-checkbox" value="2"  /> 2
  <ul>
    <li><input type='checkbox' class="build-checkbox" value="3"  /> 3</li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li><input type='checkbox' class="build-checkbox" value="4"  /> 4
  <ul>
    <li><input type='checkbox' class="build-checkbox" value="3"  /> 3</li>
     <li><input type='checkbox' class="build-checkbox" value="5"  /> 5</li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li><input type='checkbox' class="build-checkbox" value="6"  /> 6
  <ul>
    <li><input type='checkbox' class="build-checkbox" value="5"  /> 5</li>
     <li><input type='checkbox' class="build-checkbox" value="7"  /> 7</li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

JQuery:

```
    $(".build-checkbox").change(function () {
    checkAllSameUser($(this));
});

function checkAllSameUser(user) {
    var val = user.val();
    if ($(user).is(":checked")) {

        $(":checkbox[value='" + val + "']").prop("checked", true);
    }
    else {
        $(":checkbox[value='" + val + "']").prop("checked", false);
    }
};

$(function () {
    $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function () {
        $(this).siblings('ul')
             .find("input[type='checkbox']")
             .prop('checked', this.checked);
        $(this).siblings('ul').each(function () {
            checkAllSameUser($(this).find('input[type=checkbox]'));
        });
    });
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mU3FV/376/

Basically, if you hit check the '4' checkbox, then all of the '3' and '5' checkboxes on the page will also be checked (following the same logic of hitting the '3' or '5' individually). "I'm going to check each child and each matching value of each child on the page" essentially.

I'm fairly certain I'm not understanding the `.each` function or passing each sibling objects properly. I'd appreciate any input... JQuery and Javascript are not my strong points.

Comment: For each ul, call checkAllSameUser on the ul (not the checkbox) - is what your code is doing.  Within the each function, `this` refers to the current eached element, which is a ul.  You could checkAllSameUser on `$(this).find('input[type=checkbox]')` but there is more than 1 checkbox per ul.  Perhaps do your foreach on the `li` elements instead.

Comment: @James Bingo! If you want to make this an answer I will accept it. I wasn't able to find a lot of information on the each function so it may help future searchers.

Comment: @James Actually, you're right about the "more than one checkbox per ul." It seems like it will only go through the first "sibling." I've updated my JQuery and JSFiddle. I can't seem to do it on the li elements... do I have to nest another siblings or is that even possible?

Comment: I'm not totally sure about which child checkboxes you want.  Your example has a simple two-level structure but perhaps there could be more levels, and code that works as expected might be tougher to define.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for a logic as this?

```js
$(".build-checkbox").change(function() {
  checkAllSameUser($(this));
});

function checkAllSameUser(user) {
  var val = user.val();
  if ($(user).is(":checked")) {
    $(":checkbox[value='" + val + "']").prop("checked", true);
  } else {
    $(":checkbox[value='" + val + "']").prop("checked", false);
  }
};

$(function() {
  $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $(this).siblings('ul').find("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', this.checked);
    $(this).siblings('ul').find("input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
      checkAllSameUser($(this));
    });
  });
});
```

```css
li ul {
  padding-left: 25px;
  border: none;
  display: block;
}

ul {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type='checkbox' class="build-checkbox" value="1" /> 1</li>
  <li>
    <input type='checkbox' class="build-checkbox" value="2" /> 2
    <ul>
      <li>
        <input type='checkbox' class="build-checkbox" value="3" /> 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type='checkbox' class="build-checkbox" value="4" /> 4
    <ul>
      <li>
        <input type='checkbox' class="build-checkbox" value="3" /> 3</li>
      <li>
        <input type='checkbox' class="build-checkbox" value="5" /> 5</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type='checkbox' class="build-checkbox" value="6" /> 6
    <ul>
      <li>
        <input type='checkbox' class="build-checkbox" value="5" /> 5</li>
      <li>
        <input type='checkbox' class="build-checkbox" value="7" /> 7</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Note the

```
$(this).siblings('ul').find("input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
  checkAllSameUser($(this));
});
```

instead of

```
$(this).siblings('ul').each(function () {
    checkAllSameUser($(this));
});
```